# Return the result of Mysqli execute()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a DELETE query, and I want to return the result of the execution. How can I do it ?

My php code:

```
Function delete_cat($category){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE category, products FROM category INNER JOIN products WHERE category.id = ? AND product_cat = category.category_name ");
    $stmt->bind_param($category);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
//return should be here

}
```

Comment: a delete statement does not produce a result. do you want to know how many rows it deleted? http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: @Luke It's clear you mean, but you've inadvertently linked to the German version of the legacy mysql_ extension ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `$stmt->execute();` => returns a bool value, whether your query was successfully executed or not, and you can do it simply like this:

```
function delete_cat($category){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE category, products FROM category INNER JOIN products WHERE category.id = ? AND product_cat = category.category_name ");
    $stmt->bind_param($category);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
   return $result;
}
```

If you needed to get the count of the deleted elements, you can use [mysqli_stmt_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php), something like this:

```
function delete_cat($category){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE category, products FROM category INNER JOIN products WHERE category.id = ? AND product_cat = category.category_name ");
    $stmt->bind_param($category);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
   return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function delete_cat($category){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE category, products FROM category INNER JOIN products WHERE category.id = ? AND product_cat = category.category_name ");
    $stmt->bind_param($category);
    $result = $stmt->execute(); // store the return of the method into a variable here so we can return it later
    $stmt->close();
    return $result // would return if the rows have been deleted or not.
    return $mysqli->affected_rows; // would return the amount of rows deleted

}
```

If you want to get the amount of rows that have been deleted you use `affected_rows`, if you want to just get the result if the SQL query was performed succesfull, simply store the return of `$stmt->execute` into a variable and return that.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.execute.php